# Loop cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I know that my question is probably one of the most questions that has been asked but I don't know why I cannot fix the error.
I have some data in React Js that looks like that :

```
{
  title : "Marc", 
  id    : "5f4fe3af49121f1516dee853", 
  questions : [
    {
      hidden : false,
      _id    : "5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af127",
      title  : "How old are you ? "
    },{
      hidden : false,
      _id    : "5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af129",
      title  : "Where do you live"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get a number (like a counter) of how many questions are hidden in my data.
I have access to the console.log(questions) but have the famous error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Here is my code :

```
let questions = [];
questions = data.questions;
console.log(questions); // Yes
let counter;
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  console.log("hello");
  if (questions[i].hidden === false) {
    counter += 1;
  }
}
```

Console.log(questions) = [{...}, {...}]
For some reasons that I don't understand why I cannot extract my number...

Comment: try initializing your `counter` variable?  `let counter = 0;`

Comment: You could also write your loop like this: `for (let question of questions) {...}`

Comment: Missing comms (`,`) in `questions` array.

Comment: I meant "comma"...

Comment: @techWomen `...I cannot modify my data and add comas...`  You have a big problem because you have an invalid JSON.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin, why do I have an invalid JSON ? Comprends pas.
I was able to extract the question title and my title as well. I've just started coded 2 months ago so I am quite a baby in this world !

Comment: @techWomen Simplement, JSON is a subset of javascript syntax and like in javascript, you **can't** have a literal array where it's elements are not separated by comas.

Answer (score 0):

First give the comma in your questions array between objects.

```
{title : "Marc", 
id:"5f4fe3af49121f1516dee853", 
questions : [
{hidden : false, _id:"5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af127", title :"How old are you ?},
{hidden : false, _id:"5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af129", title :"Where do you live"}
]}
```

And set

```
let counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the missing comma (`,`) in `questions` array:

```js
let data ={
  title     : "Marc", 
  id        : "5f4fe3af49121f1516dee853", 
  questions : [
    {
      hidden : false,
      _id    : "5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af127",
      title  : "How old are you ? "
    }, {
      hidden : false,
      _id    : "5f4fe6e30a8a04164d0af129",
      title  : "Where do you live"
    }
  ]
};
let questions = [];
questions = data.questions;
console.log(questions); // Yes
let counter;
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  console.log("hello");
  if (questions[i].hidden === false) {
    counter += 1;
  }
}
```